# Accessing protected member

Tags: c++, generics

Why it says 'data' identifier not found? Protected members are supposed to be available in child class. Is there a problem in template? I'm new in coding, keep that in mind.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    protected:
        T data;
    };

    class C : public B
    {
        void f()
        {
            std::cout << data;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Try `this->data` or `B::data`. There's a duplicate for this question.

Comment: It's to make sure the compiler realizes that data is a dependent name, I can't find the most relevant duplicate right now.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a good question, despite the duplicate. And without knowing that you have to use `this->` it would be hard to find that particular duplicate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates by the way.